# Is it possible to get a time series of reputation from the Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, data-explorer

I would like to know the reputation score from a certain user on some specific moments in the past, is there the possibility of recovering this with the SQL language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to make a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1170724/reputation-graph#resultSets) for this based on [an older one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/882556/reputation-gained-until-a-certain-date) created by [@Magisch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/308386/magisch). Some things are missing:

- The association bonus
- Given downvotes on answers (they cost 1 reputation)
- Suggested edits where the final approval was given by a now deleted user or on deleted posts. Those votes are attributed to the Community user, but filtering those out is hard – I got lost when I discovered the 60 days / 3 score rule comes into play in various forms.

It produces a graph which is similar but not identical to your official reputation graph.

[image]

Comment: This is what makes SE so magic: having the possibility to benefit from good users like you and @Magisch of their experience and sometimes also of their ability to understand your problem better than yourself.